# Shower Door Hinge Pulling Away From Wall?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower, screws, hinges

The top hinge of our shower door is pulling away from the wall, which causes the door to sag and leave a little gap when it's open. I tried pushing the hinge back into place and tightening the screws, but they simply can't be tightened anymore, and I don't want to strip them. What is the easiest way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the screws go into is no longer holding.

So you need to find out what it is and then redo the support there.

If it is wood then I would drill a larger hole and glue a wood dowel in there and, once dry, drill pilot holes and resecure with the screws or even new screws.

If brick / masonry, t6hen perhaps gluing rawlplugs in may work or drilling and fitting larger diameter plugs may work.

Comment: Do you think I could get away with just using longer screws? I was hoping not to have to remove the door and to just replace one screw at a time. It is wood, and it only pulls away from the wall slightly, with that first picture showing the max amount it can go.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some glue on a match stick and tap into the hole. A few hours later reinstall the screw, a longer one would help. Then repeat for the other screw. I am assuming these are fastened to a stud or some backing installed for this purpose. You might also check the lower hinges to be safe.